# Need help making modifications to a geodesic sphere using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm tinkering with a slowly-rotating geodesic sphere, and I was hoping you guys could help me make some tweaks:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QaYQBd

(The code is based on this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3057239)

```
var width = 1000,
    height = 500;

var velocity = [.002, .002],
    t0 = Date.now();

var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
    .scale(height / 2 - 10);

var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

context.strokeStyle = "#fa0";
context.lineWidth = 0.5;

geodesic(3);

d3.timer(function() {
  var time = Date.now() - t0;
  projection.rotate([time * velocity[0], time * velocity[1]]);
  redraw();
});

function redraw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  faces.forEach(function(d) {
    d.polygon[0] = projection(d[0]);
    d.polygon[1] = projection(d[1]);
    d.polygon[2] = projection(d[2]);
  });

  context.beginPath();
  faces.forEach(function(d) {
      drawTriangle(d.polygon);
  });
  context.stroke();
}

function drawTriangle(triangle) {
  context.moveTo(triangle[0][0], triangle[0][1]);
  context.lineTo(triangle[1][0], triangle[1][1]);
  context.lineTo(triangle[2][0], triangle[2][1]);
  context.closePath();
}

function geodesic(n) {

  faces = d3.geodesic.polygons(n).map(function(d) {
    d = d.coordinates[0];
    d.polygon = d3.geom.polygon(d.map(projection));
    return d;
  });

  redraw();
}
```

I've been able to modify the code to get the design of the sphere closer to what I want. I'm not sure how to progress any further.

My goals:

1. Add dots to each vertex like this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3055104
2. Give the sphere a 3d perspective instead of being flat (Check out this design, which has a slider that lets you adjust the perspective: http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/GeodesicIcosahedron3.html)
3. Have the stroke widths and dot sizes change relative to the perspective (this will make the whole thing have a more 3d solid look to it, instead of having the same stroke widths for every line segment)
4. Move the sphere to an arbitrary position within the canvas and allow the canvas size to change depending on the width of the browser window
5. Randomize the rotation and starting position of the sphere when the page reloads

If anyone can help me achieve any of these goals, I'd be ecstatic!

Comment: I would help (If I had time), but this is a whole project , not single question :)

Comment: That's fair. I realize I'm asking a lot.

I might not even be using the best library here. D3 is powerful, but p5.js might be a better route to go, now that I think about it.